# ios: sync data files to application folder

Tags: ios, itunes, synchronization

If I want a .mp3 or .png file to sync with my APP in ios, How can I do this?

I dont ant my data to be stored in the general library folder.  I want to be able to tell itunes to save it to my application's document folder.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include UIFileSharingEnabled -> YES into your Info.plist file. After a sync with iTunes, your app will be enabled for sharing documents in your device's "Apps" section in iTunes.

Cheers